# How do I find a previously discovered system?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Long story short, I rushed a few jumps early in the game to finish a story mission. I then wanted to go back to a planet that was very rich in resources and whatnot, but I was unable. I didn't find a way to set a waypoint or anything similar from the discoveries page, and trying to point and click in the star map is almost impossible.

**Is there an easy way to go back to a system that you've already discovered?**

Comment: If i could take karma from my other SE accounts and add to this bounty, I would. The single most annoying aspect of this game is the complete lack of historical logging, from the the galactic map all the way down to showing where you've been on a planet. It's as iff there was a design decision made to thwart any notion of backtracking. If there's supposed to be any kind of trading, the game absolutely needs historical features.

Comment: @monsto Bet you were happy when the space station teleporter was added :)

Comment: @flarn2006 i've not played the new update yet to any real level, but I can't wait to try it. Thanks for pinging the zombie post, mate, and giving me yet another reason to try it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility is to use the scan for discoveries from the galactic map.

In the `1.03` version of the game on consoles this is <kbd>d-pad up</kbd> and on Windows <kbd>tab</kbd> is bugged, but trying <kbd>x</kbd> could work.

After I had jumped to several star systems away, I used this feature and found my already discovered systems.

This enabled me to locate where I had been and allowed me to warp back.

Comment: Naming planets and systems in a memorable way should be helpful. If you find planet "Goldy McGolderson (Gold!!)" that's one of my ways to better navigate the universe.

Comment: Pressing 'Tab', to scan for discoveries, for me doesn't do anything. Do you require any technological upgrades or pieces of equipment to enable this scan?

Comment: I've found the button mapping doesn't work, so pressing tab does nothing for me, yet using my Xbox One controller, and pressing d-pad up, I get a scan system.

Comment: The **TAB** key doesn't work, but **X** does. Once scanned, use **X** again to cycle through your discovered systems.

Comment: On PS4 the scan for discoveries feature is bugged. Sometimes it works and makes the previous discoveries have four animated lines coming out of them. But the scan never completes.

Comment: The port to Pc is really bad. Button mapping doesn't always work. For a game which costs around 60, that's a bad work.

Answer (score 4):

According to a post by *IamI3rian* yesterday on Gamefaqs:

> If you enter the galaxy map you'll have the option to search for discoveries. All discoveries. This means yours show up too. Just click find closest... etc and you're all the way back to where you need to go, without much hassle. You might need to enter freemode once or twice if you're jumping far, then short then far again at certain points, but it's not tough.
>
> Just look for the named stars.

Source: https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/739857-no-mans-sky/74158734

Quote is from the very first post.

Answer (score 1):

I've only played the game for a few hours so far but I don't think there is an easier way to do this. I believe that this is intentional so that you continue exploring new planets and finding new means for resources as you progress through the universe.